# Will app gets rejected using NSURLConnection?(Just for Info)

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am working on a project which was developed during iOS 7 and in it NSURLConnection and ABAddressBook are used,I have to add some features in it.But have a query will the app get rejected coz of NSURLConnection and ABAddressBook.

(Note- It is not version control app.App will be submitted with new bundle id and version)

Comment: It should not, since those are Apple-provided APIs.

Comment: Why do you think your app might be rejected for using these classes?

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-drops-ipv4-internet-support/


What it says, seems that we must use NSURLSession to support ipv6

Comment: ZDNet's API list is just incomplete.  NSURLConnection fully supports IPv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the API's which are provided by Apple to use publicly and not the private one. So, There are no chances to reject your app if You are using **ABAddressBook** & **NSURLConnection**.

But, Please make sure that other features that You wanted to add does not violate the Apple's guidelines..

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-drops-ipv4-internet-support/

What it says, seems that we must use NSURLSession to support ipv6

Comment: Nope.  NSURLConnection handles IPv6 just fine.  The magic happens as part of the resolver code, which is shared between both APIs.  More to the point, **all** Cocoa-level APIs handle things transparently as long as your code never touches IP addresses directly, e.g. by resolving names yourself and passing the IP address(es) to some API.